# Solving method overloading error in scala with the type system

Tags: scala, types

I have some code that compares a document with another and outputs pointers to fields that have changed, with the old and new values.

Some elements of the document have a `sequenceId` captured by this trait:

```
trait ExplicitlySequencedObject {
  val sequenceId: Int
}
```

Elements in the document that can be compared also extend a utility trait called `DiffTools` which includes the following method signatures:

```
trait DiffTools[T] {
def createDiff[E <: DiffTools[E]](original: Seq[E], current: Seq[E], pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer): DocumentDiff

def createDiff[E <: DiffTools[E]](original: Option[Seq[E]], current: Option[Seq[E]], pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer): DocumentDiff
}
```

Some elements are not explicitly sequenced, but where they are I want `createDiff` to work differently from this implementation, so method signatures like the following are added to `DiffTools` in addition to the above:

```
  def createDiff[S <: DiffTools[S] with ExplicitlySequencedObject](
    original: Seq[S],
    current: Seq[S],
    pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer
  ): DocumentDiff

  def createDiff[S <: DiffTools[S] with ExplicitlySequencedObject](
    original: Option[Seq[S]],
    current: Option[Seq[S]],
    pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer
  ): DocumentDiff
```

When I do this I get a compiler error `method createDiff is defined twice` and I'm guessing this is related to type erasure? I'd like to know why exactly this doesn't work.

Anyway I've solved the problem for now by just renaming the method (KISS, right?) but I'm thinking this is not the best scala has to offer in solving this with its fancy type system, so other approaches would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear how those pieces of code are connected. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/uyueMhKlQguPHak5oD1mEA/4 compiles without errors. How to reproduce `method createDiff is defined twice`?

Comment: My apologies, I have now clarified that all four method sigs are in the trait `DiffTools`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can add one more type parameter

```
trait DiffTools[T, Upper] {
  def createDiff[E <: DiffTools[E, Upper] with Upper](original: Seq[E], current: Seq[E], pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer): DocumentDiff
  def createDiff[E <: DiffTools[E, Upper] with Upper](original: Option[Seq[E]], current: Option[Seq[E]], pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer): DocumentDiff
}
```

and have implementations of two sorts

```
class DiffToolsImpl[T] extends DiffTools[T, Any] {
  override def createDiff[E <: DiffTools[E, Any]](original: Seq[E], current: Seq[E], pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer): DocumentDiff = ???
  override def createDiff[E <: DiffTools[E, Any]](original: Option[Seq[E]], current: Option[Seq[E]], pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer): DocumentDiff = ???
}

class ExplicitlySequencedDiffToolsImpl[T] extends DiffTools[T, ExplicitlySequencedObject] {
  override def createDiff[S <: DiffTools[S, ExplicitlySequencedObject] with ExplicitlySequencedObject](
    original: Seq[S],
    current: Seq[S],
    pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer
  ): DocumentDiff = ???

  override def createDiff[S <: DiffTools[S, ExplicitlySequencedObject] with ExplicitlySequencedObject](
    original: Option[Seq[S]],
    current: Option[Seq[S]],
    pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer
  ): DocumentDiff = ???
}
```

Also you could comsider to replace F-bounds and overloading (one flavor of ad hoc polymorhism) with type classes (another flavor of ad hoc polymorphism)

http://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html

Something like

```
trait DiffTools[A] {
  def createDiff(original: A, current: A, pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer): DocumentDiff
}
trait LowPriorityDiffTools {
  implicit def seq[E]: DiffTools[Seq[E]] = new DiffTools[Seq[E]] {
    override def createDiff(original: Seq[E], current: Seq[E], pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer): DocumentDiff = ???
  }
  implicit def optSeq[E]: DiffTools[Option[Seq[E]]] = new DiffTools[Option[Seq[E]]] {
    override def createDiff(original: Option[Seq[E]], current: Option[Seq[E]], pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer): DocumentDiff = ???
  }
}
object DiffTools extends LowPriorityDiffTools {
  implicit def explicitSeq[E <: ExplicitlySequencedObject]: DiffTools[Seq[E]] = new DiffTools[Seq[E]] {
    override def createDiff(original: Seq[E], current: Seq[E], pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer): DocumentDiff = ???
  }
  implicit def explicitOptSeq[E <: ExplicitlySequencedObject]: DiffTools[Option[Seq[E]]] = new DiffTools[Option[Seq[E]]] {
    override def createDiff(original: Option[Seq[E]], current: Option[Seq[E]], pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer): DocumentDiff = ???
  }

  def createDiff[A](original: A, current: A, pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer)(implicit diffTools: DiffTools[A]): DocumentDiff =
    diffTools.createDiff(original, current, pointerString)
}

class ExplicitlySequencedObjectImpl extends ExplicitlySequencedObject {
  override val sequenceId: Int = 100
}

val opt: Option[Seq[ExplicitlySequencedObjectImpl]] = Some(Seq(new ExplicitlySequencedObjectImpl()))
DiffTools.createDiff(opt, opt, new DocumentFieldPointer {})
```

Type classes would be the most flexible approach.

The minimal change to your original code would be `DummyImplicit`, @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez is correct

```
trait DiffTools[T] {
  def createDiff[E <: DiffTools[E]](original: Seq[E], current: Seq[E], pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer): DocumentDiff

  def createDiff[E <: DiffTools[E]](original: Option[Seq[E]], current: Option[Seq[E]], pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer): DocumentDiff

  def createDiff[S <: DiffTools[S] with ExplicitlySequencedObject](
    original: Seq[S],
    current: Seq[S],
    pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer
  )(implicit dummyImplicit: DummyImplicit): DocumentDiff

  def createDiff[S <: DiffTools[S] with ExplicitlySequencedObject](
    original: Option[Seq[S]],
    current: Option[Seq[S]],
    pointerString: DocumentFieldPointer
  )(implicit dummyImplicit: DummyImplicit): DocumentDiff
}
```

Comment: Nice to know I can do this, although I believe I'm going to stick with renaming the method given the amount of change involved.
I think I was angling for some degree of automaticity here, so that there would be one implementation of `DiffTools` and it would simply recognise when it's being fed a certain type and invoke the according implementation.
Am I right in thinking that this is what typeclasses would get me?

Comment: @TomRobinson I guess so. See some code in update.

Comment: What about just using the `DummyImplicit`?

Comment: `DummyImplicit` looks like the easiest drop-in solution, feels hacky though :)